# Error wss://mqtt.eclipse.org when create mqtt client

Tags: javascript, eclipse, websocket, mqtt

I am in my first mqtt project and my project is ok in local. But when I deployed it to heroku, It failed.
This is the error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://showbd.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to 
>       connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://mqtt.eclipse.org/mqtt'. This request has been 
>       blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.
>       k._doConnect @ mqttws31.min.js:36
>       k.connect @ mqttws31.min.js:31
>       I.connect @ mqttws31.min.js:65
>       (anonymous) @ app.js:10

I declared client in app.js file.

```js
    var MQTT_CLIENT = new Paho.MQTT.Client("mqtt.eclipse.org", Number(80), "/mqtt", MQTT_CLIENT_ID);
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the browser keeping you secure under the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

The web page that you have deployed had been securely loaded over HTTPS, to prevent unsecured content being mixed in with this it will block any connection to a none TLS protected location. In this case you are trying to make a unsecured connection the `mqtt.eclipse.org` on port 80.

The solution is to tell the Paho client to connect to the Secure Websocket endpoint on port 443. You can do this by passing a full URL to the Paho Client constructor

```
var MQTT_CLIENT = new Paho.MQTT.Client("wss://mqtt.eclipse.org", MQTT_CLIENT_ID);
```